# Returning input from form to screen in MVC using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am not sure if the problem is in my ViewModel or my query however I am not able to load the user's input after the submit.

This is the Action;

```
List<GetQuestionViewModel> quest = new List<GetQuestionViewModel>();
foreach (var item in db.Questions.Where(q => q.PageNumber == page).OrderBy(q => q.QuestionRanking))
        {
           quest.Add(new GetQuestionViewModel()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                QuestionOptions = db.QuestionOptions
                .Where(k => k.QuestionId == item.Id)
                .ToList(),
                Responses = db.Responses
                .Where(r => r.QuestionId == item.Id && r.UserId == userId)
                .ToList(),
               PageNumber = item.PageNumber,
                Question1 = item.Question1,
                QuestionRanking = item.QuestionRanking,
                QuestionTypeId = item.QuestionTypeId
            });
        }
        return View(quest);
```

And my ViewModel;

```
    public class GetQuestionViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Options { get; set; }
    public string QuestionOption1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionOptionRanking { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionRanking { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

I am puzzled as the IEnumerable(QuestionOptions) returns the correct fields and allows me to access them in my view although the individual fields are not listed here, but IEnumerable(Response) has the field Answer, but for some reason it is not available in my View unless I add the public string Answer. I believe this is my problem as it is returning a blank field even though the WHERE statements in my Action are met.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try:
db.Questions.Where(q => q.PageNumber == page).OrderBy(q => q.QuestionRanking).ToList()

Comment: Didn't think I needed that as all the other elements are returning the correct lists. Its pulling all the elements correctly except "Answer" from the Response table..?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. You are writing about Answer string in Response table, but I can see one property Answer in GetQuestionViewModel. Your action look like initializing action and you are writing about user input. Cant help.

Comment: That's the point; it IS an initializing action, but if the user (identified by userId) has already entered a response, I want it to appear when I initialize the page. Do you understand now?

Comment: Try add before "quest.Add(new GetQuestionViewModel()"...this code
var test = db.Responses.Where(r => r.QuestionId == item.Id && r.UserId == userId).ToList();
add breakpoint and look into test.

Comment: Yes, this query does return the row that meets the conditions, but now how do I get the correct field out of the record and incorporate into the quest.Add??

Comment: What do you mean by "IEnumerable(Response) has the field Answer"? Is `Answer` a property of `Response`?

Comment: If you mean is Answer a field in the Response table, yes. I am currently trying Answer =  test.Select(r => r.Answer.ToString) in my quest.Add function, but I am having no luck with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Krahu you set me on the right track! Using your code and adding the Select for the field I wanted;

```
var reply = db.Responses
.Where(r => r.QuestionId == item.Id && r.UserId == userId)
.Select(r => r.Answer)
.ToList();
```

then adding

```
Answer = reply.First()
```

to my quest.Add function worked a treat!! Many thanks!

Hmm. I may have to change that reply.First() to .Single() as I will want to capture the next item in the list too, but I'll test for that tomorrow!